# How do I convert this "array of bytes" to PDF in ROR (Ruby)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf

Over the web service, I am returned an array of bytes. Part of which looks like the following... How do I get this back to a file? (It started as a pdf)

```
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
```

Ive tried a few things, the closest is as follows (though I am unsure by the output if it is correct):

```
File.open(pdf_filename, 'w' ) do |output|
   byteArray.each_byte do | byte |
        output.print byte
        puts byte
   end
end
```

which returns in the console the following but does not create a valid file ( I assume these numbers are the bytes in Integer (base10)form or something?) :

```
77
52
79
89
    57
   etc..
```

Comment: is this relevant: http://www.continuousgreg.com/blog/?p=26? a few places seem to be saying for writing binary you need to open it with "wb" option (e.g. http://strugglingwithruby.blogspot.com/2008/11/ruby-file-access.html)

Comment: Are you sure this string is not encoded in some way, for example base64?

Comment: @taro, please see the answer below. I identified it as base64 from the given website -> and unpacked it with the "m" parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am no expert.. I am learning ruby myself at the moment (looking at questions on SO to vary techniques a bit ;-)

but have you tried:

```
File.open(pdf_filename, 'wb' ) do |output|
   byteArray.each_byte do | byte |
       output.print byte
       puts byte
   end
end
```

or maybe even (I really don't know if that will work) I don't have Ruby installed here to test:

```
File.open(pdf_filename, 'wb') { |output|
    output << byteArray
}
```

I got this info from here (among other places):

http://strugglingwithruby.blogspot.com/2008/11/ruby-file-access.html

> Binaries files are just the same; you just add a b to the second parameter of the open method.

Depending on your byte array format, you may need to use the unpack method.

```
File.open(pdf_filename, 'wb' ) do |output|
   output << byteArray.unpack("m")
end
```

See the following for possible parameters in the unpack method:
http://www.codeweblog.com/ruby-string-pack-unpack-detailed-usage/

Comment: Valid suggestions. I did actually just try both of them following your comment on my question! but with no luck. I managed to read in and then write out a byte file. But using the "byte array" coming from the webservice, no success :( . So my guess is there is a problem with this "byte array" and im currently exploring how to make it a byte string or something so that your latter suggestion would work.

Comment: ah, thanks for the feed back.. If you have time to answer: for your local read and write of the file that was successful was the addition of the "b" critical or does it work anyway? (just for my own learning..)

Comment: I just figured it out. Like i said about trying to get this "byte array" to a byte string, I stumbled accross this website with many different unpack examples, (Ive tried unpack previously). http://www.codeweblog.com/ruby-string-pack-unpack-detailed-usage/  Fortunately, looking at the examples, I found one that looked like similar garbage, and so gave the "m" param a try.. and out of all the possiblities it worked first time! So using your latter code, with .unpack("m") worked!  As for the "b" tag on write function, it doesnt seem to make a difference. Maybe thats only on windows?

Comment: cool! thanks for the info.. I like "looked like similar garbage", that would have been where I started ;-)... put up the answer and I will upvote you.

Comment: Ive just added my answer to the bottom of urs :)